# TCPClient stream irregularities?

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I have a TCPClient that creates a stream that I read from when DataAvailable.

Every 20 seconds that !DataAvailable I ping the socket with an ACK message to keep the stream from closing.

But I seem to be getting mixed results. It seems like every other time I open the stream(basically restart my Service) I get transport errors.

This is a shortened version of my Connect function:

```
client = new StreamClient();
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(clientAddress, senderPort));
stream = client.GetStream();
bool status = SendMessage(seq, sync, MessageTypes.Init);
```

The SendMessage function does:

```
if (stream == null) return false;
stream.Write(TransmitBuffer, 0, TransmitMessageLength);
```

My Close function does:

```
if (stream != null)
{
    SendMessage(seq, sync, MessageTypes.Finish);
    stream.Close();
}
stream = null;

client.Close();
client = null;
```

It is expected that the SendMessage calls will fail occasionally due to nature of the socket.

But sometimes, once I Connect, everything runs fine, no failed messages. But other times the ACK's will fail. When the ACK's fail, I call Close, which will force a Connect and validate the other end of the socket is open. If that fails then I know that end is down. But sometimes that call doesn't fail and then 20 seconds later the ACK does.

Can anyone give me an opinion on why this may happen? Is 20 seconds too long to wait? Am I not closing my end of the socket properly?

The specific error message i'm fighting with is:

```
Unable to write data to the transport connection: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine.
```

And it occurs at `stream.Write(TransmitBuffer, 0, TransmitMessageLength);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing I see in your implementation that jumps out at me is that it looks like you're treating the Stream as the Connection, and it isn't.  Your checks on the Stream instance should instead be checks on the TcpClient instance.  I'm not sure if that's the source of your problem, but it definitely looks strange to me.

Instead of this:

```
stream = client.GetStream();
if (stream != null)
{
    SendMessage(seq, sync, MessageTypes.Finish);
    stream.Close();
}
stream = null;
```

I usually do something more like this:

```
if (client != null)
{
    if (client.Connected)
    {
        client.GetStream().Close();
    }

    client.Close();
    client = null;
}
```

You should be checking TcpClient.Connected before working with the stream, not the stream itself.
Another thing I would mention is to be sure to always use the async methods to connect, read, and write with your TcpClient.  The synchronous ones are easier, but my experience has been that relying on them can get you into trouble.

Comment: I do check the TCPClient for null before attempting to close the stream, that line was simply left out for the sake of brevity. And i'm afraid the issue has more to do with keeping the stream alive than when I shut things down.

Comment: I can almost guarantee that any problems in your code are in the part that you haven't shown.  That's just the way it tends to be.  Perhaps you can post a link to an unedited version?  Regardless, that's a synchronous Connect method you're using.  You can try swapping all synchronous methods for the asynchronous equivalents and retesting your program.

Answer (score 1):

In general, putting a protocol on top of TCP is a big mistake.  It can only make the connection *less* reliable.  TCP already makes a very strong guarantee that data sent from one machine is going to be received by another one on a network.  Only very gross external circumstances can make that fail.  Things like equipment power loss or unscheduled reboots.

A connection should *not* be broken unless one of the machines intentionally closes the socket.  Which should of course always be done in a predictable way.  A logical end to a transaction or an explicit message that a machine is signing-off.

You didn't give any motivation for adding this "ACK protocol" to your connection logic, other than "keep the stream from closing".  I think what you are seeing here is that it just doesn't work, it does not in fact keep the stream from closing.  So it still goes wrong like it did before you added the protocol layer, you are still getting unexpected "An established connection was aborted" exceptions.

An example of how you made it *less* reliable is the 20 second timeout check you added.  TCP doesn't use a 20 second timeout.  It uses an exponential back-off algorithm to check for timeouts.  Typically it doesn't give up until at least 45 seconds have passed.  So you'll declare the connection dead *before* TCP does so.

Hard to give advice on how to move forward with this.  But clearly it is not by adding a protocol, you tried it and it did not work.  You will have to find out why the connection is getting broken unexpectedly.  Unfortunately that does require leg-work, you have to get insight in the kind of network equipment and software that sits between your machine and the server.  With some expectation that the problem is located at the other end of the wire since that's the one that's hardest to diagnose.  Getting the site's network admin involved with your problem is an important first step.

Comment: I do not understand how attempting to write to the stream every 20 seconds makes it less reliable. I determine that the connection has timeout because the stream tells me it has closed. The ACK messages are there from an existing application. I am upgrading that application to a Windows Service.

Comment: I don't know enough about what you actually do with those ACK messages.  But I assumed you used them to detect something wrong with the connection.  Which makes it less reliable, it is already TCP's job to do this and it uses different rules.

Comment: I send them to essentially reset the 'exponential back-off algorithm to check for timeouts' because this is a 24/7 Service and there can be large periods of time where messages are not sent to my Service.

Comment: I suppose my ACK messages are my own custom Keep Alive messages

Comment: Why are you using your own custom keep alive messages instead of using TCP keep alives?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem when developing a [network communication library](http://www.networkcomms.net). Rather than use ACK we found the most reliable solution was just to send some null data (aka keep alive). In this case byte[1] with a zero value. This would result in either:

1. A successful send and the data could be ignored on the
   receive end.
2. A failed send which would immediately cause the connection to be closed and reestablished.

Either of these outcomes ensured the connection was always in a useable state.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you send ACK? You should send SYN.

And you shouldn't send ACK, SYN, RST or setting any other flag for that matter. You're dabbling with TCP internals. You're creating Application level protocol and keeping-alive is part of that, cause, iirc, even there is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee470551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx connection will be open until you close it.